# Get Navigation Properties of given EntityType

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ado.net

I am using **VS2010, EF4.0**. Need function like the following.

```
private string[] GetNaviProps(Type entityType)//eg typeof(Employee)
{
    NorthwindEntities en = new NorthwindEntities();
    //here I return all Properties only for example
    return entityType.GetProperties().Select(p=>p.Name).ToArray();
    //should return Orders,Territories...
}
```

I have checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251863/entity-framework-check-if-%20%20property-is-navigation-property), but IObjectContextAdapter seems something in EF6.0 and .net4.5. I tried to replace it like

```
var workspace = en.MetadataWorkspace;
```

So it can compile, but exception throw at the 3nd line then.
Any help?

Comment: I think you can use the code in the link if you take `CSpace` in stead of `OSpace`. `OSpace` used to get initialized not before the first call to an `ObjectSet`.

Comment: @Gert Arnold tried but not worked either. Could you post your code also? I think get the properties directly is always more precise and stable than the currently marked answer.

Comment: But this is the kind of code I would use as well (i.e. accessing the metadata). Apparently there's been a major change after EF4.0.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can filter `GetProperties` results to get only these which implement `ICollection` or `IEnumerable`. However, you should remember that `string` implements `IEnumerable`, so you have to add additional check not to return `string` properties.

```
return entityType.GetProperties()
                 .Where(p => typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType) && p.PropertyType != string)
                 .Select(p => p.Name)
                 .ToArray();
```

**Update**

You can change you `Where` predicate to compare namespaces as well. It returns also 1:1 navigation properties:

```
private static string[] GetNaviProps(Type entityType)//eg typeof(Employee)
{
    return entityType.GetProperties()
                     .Where(p => (typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType) && p.PropertyType != typeof(string)) ||  p.PropertyType.Namespace == entityType.Namespace)
                     .Select(p => p.Name)
                     .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The code works for m:n Navigation Properties, but in relationship of 1:m, the Navigation Properties may not be IEnumerable, instead they are singles. How to also filter them?

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38846019/5306861) answer

```cs
    private static List<PropertyInfo> GetNavigationProperties(Type t)
    {

        var navigationProperties = new List<PropertyInfo>();

        if (t.BaseType != null && t.Namespace == "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies") {
            t = t.BaseType;
        }

        string fkName = t.Name + "Id";

        var allProps = new List<PropertyInfo>();

        foreach (PropertyInfo p in t.GetProperties()) {
            if (p.PropertyType.IsGenericType) {
                dynamic GenericTypeDefinition = p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
                if (GenericTypeDefinition == typeof(ObservableCollection<>) || GenericTypeDefinition == typeof(ICollection<>) || GenericTypeDefinition == typeof(IEnumerable<>)) {
                    allProps.Add(p);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in allProps) {
            // This checks if the other type has a FK Property of this Type.
            var type = prop.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments().First();

            bool HasOneProperty = type.GetProperties().Any(x => x.Name.Equals(fkName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            if (HasOneProperty) {
                navigationProperties.Add(prop);
            }

        }

        return navigationProperties;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm a little late to the party, but you can use the Entity Framework way to retrieve the navigation properties instead of using reflection:

```
MetadataWorkspace workspace = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this.Context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;    
ObjectItemCollection itemCollection = (ObjectItemCollection)(workspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.OSpace));   
EntityType entityType = itemCollection.OfType<EntityType>().Single(e => itemCollection.GetClrType(e) == typeof(TEntity));
```

where `this.Context` is an instance of the `DbContext` class. After that you can access the EntityType's NavigationProperties property.

Comment: For now at least as the ObjectContext is obsolete and will probably be not included in Entity Framework 7.

Comment: No evidence that ObjectContext is obsolete: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.core.objects.objectcontext(v=vs.113).aspx  and even if the access method will be different, it is impossible to "obsolete" root of metamodel.

Comment: @RomanPokrovskij I think the github repo is enough evidence: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore

Comment: Ok you are talking about Ef Core. There they have context.Model, then model.FindEntityType(source.Type) .

Answer (score -5):

**Linq and Entity Frameworks with grouped report**

public static string strMessage = "";
        public SchoolEntities dbContext;

```
    public string login(string strUsername, string strPassword)
    {
        dbContext = new SchoolEntities();

        var linqQuery = from User in dbContext.People
                        where User.FirstName == strUsername && User.LastName == strPassword
                        select User;

        if (linqQuery.Count() == 1)
        {
            strMessage = "Good";
        }
        else
        {
            strMessage = "Bad";
        }

        return strMessage;

    }
    public Object LoadPersonDetails()
    {
        dbContext = new SchoolEntities();
        var linqQuery = from users in dbContext.People
                        select users;
        return linqQuery;
    }

    public void InsertPerson(string strLName, string strFName, string strHireDate, string EnrollmentDate)
    {
        dbContext = new SchoolEntities();
        Person NewPerson = dbContext.People.Create();

        NewPerson.LastName = strLName;
        NewPerson.FirstName = strFName;
        NewPerson.HireDate = Convert.ToDateTime(strHireDate);
        NewPerson.EnrollmentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(EnrollmentDate);

        dbContext.People.Add(NewPerson);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    public void DeleteUser(int intPersonID)
    {
        using (dbContext = new SchoolEntities())
        {
            Person Person = dbContext.People.Where(c => c.PersonID == intPersonID).FirstOrDefault();
            if (Person != null)
            {
                dbContext.People.Remove(Person);
                dbContext.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
    public void ModifyPerson(int intPersonID, string strLName, string strFName, string strHireDate, string EnrollmentDate)
    {
        dbContext = new SchoolEntities();
        var UpdatePerson = dbContext.People.FirstOrDefault(s => s.PersonID == intPersonID);

        UpdatePerson.LastName = strLName;
        UpdatePerson.FirstName = strFName;
        UpdatePerson.HireDate = Convert.ToDateTime(strHireDate);
        UpdatePerson.EnrollmentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(EnrollmentDate);

        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    private Excel.Application XApp = null; //Creates the Excel Document
    private Excel.Workbook XWorkbook = null; //create the workbook in the recently created document
    private Excel.Worksheet XWorksheet = null; //allows us to work with current worksheet
    //private Excel.Range XWorkSheet_range = null; // allows us to modify cells on the sheet

    public void Reports()
    {
        dbContext = new SchoolEntities();

        var linqQuery = (from users in dbContext.StudentGrades
                         group users by new { users.EnrollmentID, users.CourseID, users.StudentID, users.Grade }
                         into UserGroup
                         orderby UserGroup.Key.CourseID ascending
                         select new { UserGroup.Key.EnrollmentID, UserGroup.Key.CourseID, UserGroup.Key.StudentID, UserGroup.Key.Grade }).ToList();

        var RatingAverage = dbContext.StudentGrades.Average(r => r.Grade);

        var GradeSum = dbContext.StudentGrades.Sum(r => r.Grade);

        /*var linqQuery = (from users in dbContext.StudentGrades
                         orderby users.CourseID descending
                         select users).ToList();*/

        //Array Motho = linqQuery.ToArray();

        var GradeInfo = linqQuery.ToList();

        XApp = new Excel.Application();
        XApp.Visible = true;
        XWorkbook = XApp.Workbooks.Add(1);
        XWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)XWorkbook.Sheets[1];

        //Create column headers
        XWorksheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Standard Student Grades Report";
        XWorksheet.Cells[2, 1] = "EnrollmentID";
        XWorksheet.Cells[2, 2] = "CourseID";
        XWorksheet.Cells[2, 3] = "StudentID";
        XWorksheet.Cells[2, 4] = "Grade";

        int row = 3;

        foreach (var Mothos in linqQuery)
        {
            XWorksheet.Cells[row, 1] = Mothos.EnrollmentID.ToString();
            XWorksheet.Cells[row, 2] = Mothos.CourseID.ToString();
            XWorksheet.Cells[row, 3] = Mothos.StudentID.ToString();
            XWorksheet.Cells[row, 4] = Mothos.Grade.ToString();

            row++;
        }

        int rows = linqQuery.Count();

        XWorksheet.Cells[rows + 4, 3] = "Grades Average";
        XWorksheet.Cells[rows + 4, 4] = RatingAverage.Value.ToString();

        XWorksheet.Cells[rows + 5, 3] = "Grades Sum";
        XWorksheet.Cells[rows + 5, 4] = GradeSum.Value.ToString();

        XWorksheet.Rows.Columns.AutoFit();
    }

    public void GroupedExcel()
    { 
        dbContext = new SchoolEntities();

        var linqQuery = from Grading in dbContext.StudentGrades
                        orderby Grading.CourseID
                        select Grading;

        var lstGrades = linqQuery.ToList();

        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlApp.Visible = true;
        Excel.Workbook xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(1);
        Excel.Worksheet xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlBook.Worksheets[1];

        int GroupTotal = 0;
        int GrandTotal = 0;
        int ExcelRow = 5;
        int intTemp = lstGrades[0].CourseID;
        xlSheet.Cells[4, 1] = lstGrades[0].CourseID;

        //Create column headers
        xlSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Grouped Student Grades Report";
        xlSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "Group header";
        xlSheet.Cells[3, 2] = "EnrollmentID";
        xlSheet.Cells[3, 3] = "CourseID";
        xlSheet.Cells[3, 4] = "StudentID";
        xlSheet.Cells[3, 5] = "Grade";

        for (int count = 0; count < lstGrades.Count; count++)
        {
            if (intTemp == lstGrades[count].CourseID)
            {
                xlSheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 2] = lstGrades[count].EnrollmentID.ToString();
                xlSheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 3] = lstGrades[count].CourseID.ToString();
                xlSheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 4] = lstGrades[count].StudentID.ToString();
                xlSheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 5] = lstGrades[count].Grade.ToString();

                ExcelRow++;
                GroupTotal++;
                GrandTotal++;
            }
            else
            {
                xlSheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 5] = "Total for: " + intTemp + " = " + GroupTotal.ToString();
                ExcelRow++;
                intTemp = lstGrades[count].CourseID;
                xlSheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 1] = lstGrades[count].CourseID;
                count--;
                GroupTotal = 0;
                ExcelRow++;
            }
        }
        xlSheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 5] = "Total for: " + intTemp + " = " + GroupTotal.ToString();
        ExcelRow++;
        xlSheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 5] = "Grand Total = " + GrandTotal.ToString();

        xlSheet.Rows.Columns.AutoFit();
```

### }

'Its not what you get but what you give that makes you a richer person'

Comment: Seems no relation with my question.