# Entity Framework 6 way to check at runtime if navigation property is many-to-many or one-to-many

Tags: c#, entity-framework

For example, I have the following classes

```
class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AddressType { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

I have a way to determine at runtime if property is navigation property using ObjectContext metadata thanks to
[entity framework check if property is navigation property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251863/entity-framework-check-if-property-is-navigation-property)

But what I need additionally is to know if property is many-to-many (like Teams property in the example above) or one-to-many (like Addresses). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `User` have `ICollection<Address> Addresses` it is one to many . if `public ICollection<User> Users` have `ICollection<Address> Addresses` many to many . In other words if you have list in your class and inside you have another list it is many to many relation

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, I was also thinking about such approach. But the problem here is that other side of many-to-many relation may not have any navigation property defined. In example above Team may not have ICollection<User> Users but it still can be set as many-to-many relation

Answer (score 1):

In case someone will need same thing - here is some way of doing it:

```
var navigationProperties = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace
                        .GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace)
                        .Single(p => p.FullName == typeof(User).FullName)
                        .NavigationProperties;

var one = navigationProperties.Where(navigationProperty => navigationProperty.FromEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.One).ToList();
var many = navigationProperties.Where(navigationProperty => navigationProperty.FromEndMember.RelationshipMultiplicity == RelationshipMultiplicity.Many).ToList();
```