# API to query your Entity Framework context's model?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-data-model

I'm using EF code-first, and I'd like to identify, programatically, which properties are navigation properties, which are foreign keys, and which are Ids. Eg, in this classic Order/Item example;

```
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderItem> Items { get; set;
}

public class OrderItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
    public int ProductCount { get; set; }
}
```

As a programmer it's clear to me what's going on; `OrderItem.OrderId` is my foreign key, `OrderItem.Order` is a navigation property, and `Order.Items` is the inverse of that navgation property.  It's also clear that EF knows this, because it's gone though the model-building stage

However, I'd like to be able to do this programatically; so I'm hoping there is an API, maybe with a similar feel to Reflection, which might allow me to ask questions like;

```
 var model = CreateModelFor(salesContext);
 var foreignKeys = model.ForeignKeysFor(typeof(Order)); // ["OrderId"]
 var navigationProperties = model.NavigationPropertiesFor(typeof(Order)) // [`Order`]
```

Does such a thing exist in EF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to drop down to ObjectContext and then you can get all the information about the model by exploring [MetadataWorkspace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.metadataworkspace(v=vs.110).aspx). 
This API and the entire model behind it is quite scary (with navigation properties being the most complicated).

This thread contains an example that will help you get started: [entity framework check if property is navigation property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251863/entity-framework-check-if-property-is-navigation-property)